# How can I troubleshoot my slow 2015 Early MacBook Air 13" laptop?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, performance

I have a 2015 Early MacBook Air 13", 1.6 Ghz, 4GB RAM, 128GB SSD (with 90GB free space) running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

When I'm using Safari with only 4-5 windows open, it slows down. I have to click on something a few times for it to work, and a lot of times, my pad pointer will turn into the color wheel, meaning it's slowing down.

I keep thinking I need more RAM or the CPU is maxed. I don't have anything running in the background and I closed all my apps but this still happens.

How can I go about troubleshooting this?

**UPDATE**

I just used Google Chrome and everything is normal, IE no slowness, no waiting 3 seconds for something to happen.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site a useful resource. Your question comes across very similar to an XY problem. Basically, you have a problem (X) and decide the solution is Y, and now you've come here asking a question about Y rather than the actual problem. Can I suggest your question really needs to be about the issue you're having with the MBA running slowly? I'm sure our community can help you with this, although we need some extra details (e.g. how much free space do you have on your drive, what do you mean by *running slow*, what macOS is installed)

Comment: Thanks for providing the extra info and for clarifying things somewhat. Please note for future reference you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/343295/edit) your original question to provide additional info. In fact, could you also do that now to let us know what (if anything) you've already tried to resolve this? Also, when did you start noticing the slow down? Did it coincide with anything else (e.g. new macOS, new software, new hardware)? And can you clarify what browser you're using and if you've tried using a different one to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Corey, glad to see using Chrome doesn't cause you any problems. While this may be a suitable workaround, we still haven't got to the bottom of the issue with Safari - but you may be happy with this as it is. As for the *other* question about a replacement logic board: (1) without part numbers it's impossible to give you a definitive answer, although a original MacBook Air 1.8 GHz Logic Board should fit into an original 1.6GHz MacBook Air of the same vintage/size, (2) based on the info you've provided us it doesn't seem you'd really gain anything from upping the logic board.

Comment: Also, i dont think there is a 1.8 ghz logic board, same vintage/year.. but there is a 2.2 ghz LB same year/vintage. Will that work?

Comment: Hi Corey, just to clarify, this site works best on the basis that each question is a distinct question in its own right. Originally we changed the focus of this question so that it actually addressed the problem you were having, not the solution you thought you needed. If you're still concerned about the *Safari* issue, then we can continue to troubleshoot this (there's quite a few things we can still try).

Comment: If you're still wanting to investigate the issue of replacing the logic board then that's a totally separate question you'd need to ask. However, based on what you've shared so far, it's doubtful you have the need to try swapping out the logic board. Is there something you're hoping to gain from doing that? Are you using software that would benefit from the CPU upgrade? Something else? And yes, I apologise for my error yesterday, your particular model of MBA shipped with either a 1.6GHz or 2.2 GHz CPU.

Comment: well, i thought my question about the logic board was pretty definate.. Ok, i upgraded my OS to MacOS Majave 10.14.1 and it seems to have solved the safari problem, altho im more of a chrome user myself. and Thanks for the support

Comment: But knowing all i mentioned before, can i use the 2.2 ghz logic board?? i will be using some cpu intensive programs and also, i will be moving to Ecuador soon. Being in the mountains, id rather upgrade now while im in the states, then later.. So will my aforemention swap work??

Comment: Yes. Assuming you have the tools and competence to do the swap, the part numbers you provided earlier will be compatible. I suggest you take a look at this [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Early+2015+Logic+Board+Replacement/38529).

Comment: ok thank you for all the help :) have a happy turkey day